# Error logging and profiling a web application

Tags: tomcat

I have deployed two web applications with `tomcat7` on a `windows7` machine.  After some period of time of use any one of the application throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error.  After 2-3 minutes another application also stops to respond. So I started looking in the tomcat7 error log file `tomcat7-stderr.xxx.log`, I found logs saying that some `http-bio` threads have thrown an out of memory error.

I want to know which application throws the first error, so I want tomcat to log the application name with the error, How can I do this?

Can I check how much memeory each web application is taking from memory allocated to tomcat?

Currently tomcat has `Initial Memory Pool is 512 MB` and `Maximum memory pool is 900 MB`

Comment: You can try with visualvm or yourkit profile java

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi I tried with `visualvm` but it's not showing memory utilization web application wise. I want a tool which can show which web application is taking how much memory from allocated memory to tomcat.

Comment: if you attach to the tomcat pid, then you will get all of the threads in Tomcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know which application first throws error, so I want tomcat logs the error with the Application name, Is it possible to do?

Tomcat and all of the applications you deploy to Tomcat are running in *one* JVM.  This means that any one of those applications could be the cause, but it also means that it could be the aggregate of one or more of the apps that is causing the problem too.  In other words, you might not be able to point a finger at just one app.

That said because you're seeing an OOME: PermGen there are a few likely causes.

- You have lots (thousands) of JSPs.  Those are compiled to classes and classes increase the PermGen requirements.  This is a legit use case and if you have lots of JSPs, you just need a larger PermGen.
- You have an application that's dynamically generating classes.  Libraries like cglib will do this.  You're probably not using it directly, but lots of frameworks use it or similar libraries.  Again, I'd suggest increasing the PermGen as you may just need a little more to run the app.
- You're hot redeploying applications (where you drop a new WAR into the "webapps" directory without restarting).  This is not a problem itself, but if your application does not cleanly undeploy you'll end up with a slow memory leak that will cause you to run out of PermGen space.  If you're seeing this problem, check out [these slides](http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Memory-Leaks-60mins.pdf) in particular #11, which talk more about the issue and show how to figure out the cause.

Of these three, the last one is far and away the most likely to occur.

> Can I check which web application is taking how much memory from memory allocated to tomcat 7?

Attach a profiler or jvisualvm.  Most of them don't have great visibility into the PermGen, as they generally focus on heap usage, but they'll help.

If you're using jvisualvm, these are some helpful plugins for debugging memory related issues:  "Memory Pools", "Visual GC" and "VisualVM-BufferMonitor".

They don't come installed by default, so you have to go to Tools -> Plugins and install them.

Regardless of what tool you use, I doubt you're going to find a breakdown where it divides memory usage out by application.  An "application" is a container level concept and not one that the JVM or your profiler are likely to understand.  If you need to isolate per application memory usage, you're better off only deploying one application to Tomcat at a time.  That way you know the only stuff in memory are resources related to that app.

If you're in a production situation, you may want to consider running multiple separate Tomcat instances (one per app).  The upshot of this is that you'll have separate JVMs for each app and if one goes down, it won't take the rest of them with it.  The downside is that there will be some overhead for the additional JVM and Tomcat instance.  If you have the memory available, it's generally an acceptable tradeoff for the additional stability it offers.

> after sometime of use any one of application throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error. after 2-3 mins another application also stops to respond.

When a OOME occurs in a JVM, you need to restart the JVM as soon as possible.  After the OOME occurs, all bets are off in terms of what will and what won't continue working.  The only way to restore a sane working environment is to restart the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for such nice detail answer.